# How to use "return on"

Tags: word-usage

There is a economic [term](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roi) called "return on investment (ROI)."

I wonder if I can only use it a fixed way or if I can use it as a verb "return on" as in the following sentence?

> Most of the time, such as large investment schemes can need a
>   substantial amount of money, and it could take years to finish and
>   return on.

or do I have to use "it/them" at the end if I do  use "investment" as a subject?

> Most of the time, such as large investment schemes can need a
>   substantial amount of money, and it could take years to finish and
>   return on it.

Or should I use another subject all along at best because it is used mostly as noun?

> Most of the time, such as large  schemes/projects/programs can need a
>   substantial amount of money, and it could take years to finish and
>   realize a return on investment.

Comment: The idiom is "return on **investment**".  "Return on", by itself, has no idiomatic meaning.

Comment: You'd want to say *produce returns*, *generate returns*, *realize returns*, or some other *verb returns*.

Answer (score 9):

"Return on investment" is a *noun* phrase, and you will only confuse your readers if you try to use it as a verb.  *Return* is of course also a verb, and one of its meanings is  "To provide or bring back in exchange for effort or investment or as a result of ownership; to yield as a return. Freq. in *to return a profit*" (OED 16a: one citation is "1937   *Life 26 July 85/2 (advt.)* Big loads return the largest profit on drivers' wages"); you could make use of this to say, for example '...this could take years to return a reasonable income' if you do not wish to say 'this could take years to provide a return'.

But you seem to be asking specifically about the  verb *return on*: there is no such thing. *On* is a preposition going with *return*; ;the mere fact that two words occur together in a piece of prose does not make them a recognized phrase, far less an idiom.

Comment: The only use I can find of the verb *return* followed by *on* is in the expression ***return on** board*, meaning to re-board a ship.

Comment: @deadrat: That could be spelt 'return onboard', but it could not be '*returnon board'.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of grammatical errors in your sentence.

It is possible to use *return*, in this sense (and without the *on*) as a verb, but it wouldn't work very well here.

May I suggest that what you are saying is ***Most large schemes need substantial investment, and can take years to finish and deliver a return***.

This is not to say that *return on investment* isn't a perfectly valid term. You could equally well say; ***Most large schemes cost a lot of money, and take years to finish and deliver a return on investment***.

Comment: You might also change *deliver* to *realize*

Comment: @Jim Yes, I agree. That would be more idiomatic.